# Why were the makers of BTTF going to use a fridge as a time machine?

Tags: back-to-the-future, behind-the-scenes

So, as every good *Back to the Future* fan knows, the DeLorean wasn't in the original plan for *Back to the Future*.  The time machine was going to be a fridge (Great Scott - I'm glad they changed their minds!).  Now, they changed it from a fridge because they were afraid of kids (or *Back to the Future* fans generally) shutting themselves into a fridge.

My question is: **why did they want to use a fridge as a time machine in the first place?**

Comment: Where/why seem to be different questions..

Comment: Because in a pinch, it doubles as a nuclear blash shelter.

Comment: @TheDoc : Hadn't seen this one until now.  Great question, +1!  :-)

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Documentary](http://bgr.com/2015/10/20/back-to-the-future-documentary-netflix-streaming/), the DeLorean became the the Time Machine because it was a vehicle. There was no mention of them fearing kids would lock themselves in fridges, and in fact the Indiana Jones Lead Lined Fallout Shelter Fridge from the 4th Indy film was "borrowed" from the pre-Delorean script, as Steven Speilberg was involved with both franchises.

The script writers decided the Time Machine needed to be mobile, so you could navigate around in the past or the future. A fridge would not let you do that.

As to why a fridge was the first choice, it was part of the brainstorming process of script writing. Good ideas are (often) replaced by better ideas. In this case, the better idea was golden.

Comment: Just for the record, the fridge reference can be found on [this page](http://backtothefuture.com/delorean/creation): "When Robert Zemeckis and Bob Gale first wrote the script for Back to the Future in 1981, their concept for the time machine was originally set to be a refrigerator. Fearing that children would imitate the film and get trapped inside"

Comment: @TheDoc I just went with what they said in the documentary.

Comment: A fridge locally reverse the entropy trend. :-) In a sense it goes against time's arrow.

Comment: Presumably, a fridge would provide protection/insulation in transit and at arrival as per how Indiana Jones famously survived a nuclear blast inside a fridge.

Comment: So you could say they changed their minds due to [fridge logic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic).